# Shell command to up count version number

Tags: shell

I have a version.txt containing a version number (0.0.1) in line 1 - I want this file to be updated keeping the first to numbers and +1 the third resulting in 0.0.2 replacing the old number in the version.txt file.

How it should work:

```
$ cat version.txt
0.0.1

$ ??? SOME SHELL COMMAND ???

$ cat version.txt
0.0.2

# revision number should go on forever
# ex: running script 412 times
$ cat version.txt
0.0.413
```

How can I do that on the shell?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `awk` you can do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} NR==1{++$NF}1' file
```

It increments the last number of the dot separated string on first line. You can also just do `++$3`, but this way is more general. To update a file you can redirect to a temp file and then move:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} NR==1{++$NF}1' file > tmp_file && mv tmp_file file
```

#### Sample

```
$ cat a
hi = 1.23
1.2.33
hello

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="."} NR==1{++$NF}1' a
hi = 1.24
1.2.33
hello
```

Comment: thx, does not quite work, version pattern has to be three parts, 0.0.1, going up to 0.0.2, ... , 0.0.412

Comment: What do you mean? Where does this 412 come from? Update your question with some sample input data and desired output, because from your comment I guess I am missing something.

Comment: Aaaah now I see. Well, based on your update, my script should make it. As you marked as accepted, I guess it is fine to you.